# SQL query based on another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

I have tables like this:

table 1:

| FNAME | ID1 | FID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BREAD | XYZ | 18BREAD |
| FISH | ABC | 45FISH |
| BREAD_OLD | BNQ | 18BREAD_OLD |
| BACON | TBG | 77BACON |
| EGGS | CGS | 99EGGS |
| BANANA | BHG | BANANA18 |

table 2:

| FNAME | FID |
| --- | --- |
| BREAD | 18 |
| FISH | 45 |
| BACON | 77 |
| EGGS | 99 |

currently a simple search is done on table 1 to find id's of food as follows:

```
SELECT ID1 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE NAME IN NAME_LIST
```

so for example when the name list is: ('BREAD','FISH') then it returns XYZ, ABC. The problem is this misses 'BREAD_OLD' which is an older version with the same ID. (18)

I need to change this so now the search is done based on the FID of food rather than the NAME to find affected foods but I cannot change the input.

eg: given a list of foods: ('BREAD', 'FISH')

the result should be XYZ, ABC, BNQ (because BREAD matches 18 which matches BNQ in table 1)

how can this can be done? I think I need to use a join or do a 'select within a select' but I'm not sure how this would work with multiple inputs.

edit: ORACLE is the database
edit 2: adding BANANA18 to table 1, needs to be leading match

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: This database design is broken. Table 1's FID column should not include the value from the FNAME column. It should be identical to table 2's FID column, with a foreign key between the two. Fixing this will make your query (and others) significantly simpler, faster, more robust, easier to maintain and adapt, etc, etc.

Comment: This site uses English. PS [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: I am simplifying a real world scenario using basic example and think I messed up here, the FID in table one is not called FID, it's called something else.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified.

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. PS Your text that you use Oracle was already edited out because someone already edited in a tag after the 1st time you said it (because it should be a tag not prose).

Comment: The answers only show how to muddle through with the inappropriate data (first normalization rule violated). Instead of using one of them, you should follow MatBailie's advice above and fix your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `table1.FID` equals `table2.FID` concatenated with `table1.FNAME` then you do not need (slow) regular expressions and can use a simple equality combined with string concatenation:

```sql
SELECT t1.FNAME,
       t1.ID1
FROM   table1 t1 
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.FID = t2.fid || t1.fname
WHERE  t2.FNAME IN ('BREAD','FISH');
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (FNAME, ID1, FID) AS
SELECT 'BREAD',     'XYZ', '18BREAD'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FISH',      'ABC', '45FISH'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BREAD_OLD', 'BNQ', '18BREAD_OLD' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BACON',     'TBG', '77BACON'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EGGS',      'CGS', '99EGGS'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BANANA',    'BHG', 'BANANA18' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOAST',     'TST', 'TOAST181' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (FNAME, FID) AS
SELECT 'TOAST', 181 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BREAD',  18 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FISH',   45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BACON',  77 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EGGS',   99 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FNAME | ID1 |
> | --- | --- |
> | BREAD | XYZ |
> | BREAD_OLD | BNQ |
> | FISH | ABC |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=76e656be704eb1f7c3f2de96c60fa106)*

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution would be to link on the FID fields. However, the FID field on table1 seems to concatenate the ID with the name. The solution would therfore be to extract the numeric value from that field and then use that to link it to the FID field on table 2. For example:

```
SELECT t1.FNAME, t1.ID1
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.FID = regexp_replace(t1.FID, '^[^0-9]', '')
WHERE 
t2.FNAME IN ('BREAD','FISH');
```

Comment: that's great thanks, totally forgot to say i'm using ORACLE. do you know how to translate the PATINDEX to ORACLE?

Comment: @coder787 For oracle I would use regexp_replace, I have updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, did you mean to take out the substring?  I am getting a lot of matches now

Comment: regexp_replace is the correct oracle function to use

Comment: ah I think I see the problem, there are also other ids like this "BANANA18" in table 1, the query is also returning this one when it shouldn't, it should only be leading match.

Comment: @coder787 I have updated the query now

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1;

FNAME     ID1   FID
-------------------------
BREAD     XYZ   18BREAD
FISH      ABC   45FISH 
BACON     TBG   77BACON
EGGS      CGS   99EGGS 
BREAD_OLD BNQ   18BREAD_OLD

SELECT * FROM TABLE2;

FNAME  FID
----------
BREAD   18
FISH    45
BACON   77
EGGS    99
```

Query:

In query we join TABLE1 and TABLE2 on FID (using REGEX_SUBSTR to extract first n numbers of TABLE1 FID) so row 'BREAD_OLD' will be joined with row 'BREAD' from TABLE2 and when we add condition FNAME IN ('BREAD') both ID1 of 'BREAD' AND 'BREAD_OLD' will be selected.

```
SELECT ID1
FROM
(SELECT
TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(FID,'^[0-9]{1,}'),'9999') AS FID,FNAME,ID1
FROM TABLE1)V
JOIN TABLE2 T
ON (V.FID=T.FID)
WHERE T.FNAME IN ('BREAD','FISH')
```

Result:

```
ID1
---
XYZ
ABC
BNQ
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm getting "V.FID" is invalid identifier.

Comment: It shouldn't be invalid identifier because as you see the subquery: `(SELECT
TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(FID,'^[0-9]{1,}'),'9999') FID,FNAME,ID1
FROM TABLE1)V` has a FID column, try to add `AS` to: `TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(FID,'^[0-9]{1,}'),'9999') AS FID`. I updated my code so u can copy and past it again

Answer (score 0):

One option is joining the tables by matching concatenated columns of `table2` with the extracted substrings upto **`_`** character for `fid` column of `table1` such as

```sql
 SELECT id1
   FROM table1 t1
   JOIN table2 t2
     ON REGEXP_SUBSTR(t1.fid,'[^_]+') = t2.fid||t2.fname
  WHERE t2.fname IN ('BREAD','FISH')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d4d1bc625e1518d1b601cfccae032650)</kbd>